# Merge multiple xml files using java nodelist

Tags: java, xml, nodelist, xmlnodelist

To merger multiple xml files using nodelist I used below code but it's output file has duplicate(repeated) values.

xml files folder structure is as shown below

```
                 c:|--20140525214726/search.xml
                   |--20140525214727/search.xml
                   |--20140525214728/search.xml                      
                   |.
                   |.
                   |--20140525214736/search.xml
```

The code is:
I used int k in for loop to loop through all the folders shown above.
And appended PropertyDetails nodes of all the files from 20140525214727 to 20140525214736 to 20140525214726/search.xml file.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
domFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);  
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\20140525214726\\search.xml"));   
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("PropertyDetails");  
for(int k=26; k<=37; k++){  

   Document doc1 = builder.parse(new File("C:\\201405252147"+k+"\\search.xml"));   
   NodeList nodes1 = doc1.getElementsByTagName("PropertyDetails");

   for(int i=0;i<nodes1.getLength();i=i+1){  
                Node n= (Node) doc.importNode(nodes1.item(i), true);  
        nodes.item(i).getParentNode().appendChild(n);
             }

     } 

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();  
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  

StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());  
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);  
transformer.transform(source, result);  
Writer output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream("SeeOfXML.xml"), "UTF-8"));


String xmlOutput = result.getWriter().toString();  
output.write(xmlOutput);
output.close();
```

Is their any wrong with my code to merge multiple xml files?

Comment: What happens when you run it? Any exceptions?

Comment: @helderdarocha  no exceptions but nodes(<PropertyDetails>) are repeating(duplicate nodes)

Comment: I think I found it. You are repeating the nodes of the first file.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the first file twice. First here:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("src/main/resources/20140525214726/search.xml"));
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("PropertyDetails");
```

And then in the loop again:

```
for (int k = 26; k <= 30; k++) {
    Document doc1 = builder.parse(new File("src/main/resources/" + "201405252147" + k + "/search.xml"));
```

Since `k` is 26, you are reading the file from directory `20140525214726` again.

Change it to `27` so it will skip that file:

```
for (int k = 26; k <= 30; k++) { ... }
```

It should work now if there aren't any other problems.